# Internet having frequent outages

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am a Comcast/Xfinity customer in TX and I am currently paying for 105 Mbps speed. I am not getting these speeds and have been having frequent outages.

Comment: I can't quite tell what you are asking here. Do you want us to explain what packet loss is? Do you expect us to diagnose your connection issues? Are you hoping a Comcast representative will see this and and get in touch with you? Do you want an explanation for what these "Hosted by" mean? Or what? **Please [edit] your question to include a clear, specific question that we can answer.** See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for some suggestions how to write your post to make it more likely that you will get a good answer.

Comment: You told us what is happening, but what you did not do (as far as I can tell) was *ask a question*. You have presented some facts, but there are many questions that could be derived from those facts. I offered a few examples in my previous comment. I have no doubts that you are seeking an answer to some question, but since we aren't you, it's very hard for us to know what that question is. By simply [edit]ing your post and including the specific question that you want an answer to, someone is highly likely to be able to give you an answer, or at the very least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Talk to your ISP (Comcast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosts changing are simply the servers **speedtest.net** uses to check the speed (between your house and their server). They have different locations all around the world for you to test your speed to. You can manually choose the server, or let it automatically select based on ping (which one it can reach faster). Maybe choose the same server each time and you'll get more consistent results, but ultimately this has nothing to do with your internet.

[image]

If you're having issues with reliability of your connection, ring up your ISP. Packet loss in the router error logs are common too - so just talk to them and they should be able to send a tech out and work out the problems. But varying speedtest.net results aren't an indication of internet unreliability.